# artful release does not have a release file

Tags: apt

Hy guys, I'm having some issues trying to install VMware. I'm new to ubuntu so could you please help me?

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What do you need that repository for? Who added it to your Ubuntu installation? It does not belong to the default repositories.

Comment: 17.04 is zesty, it is EOL. Artful 17.10 is alive.

Answer (score 3):

1. There aren't any packages for Ubuntu 17.10 in ppa:ehoover/compholio, so remove this ppa from your software sources:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ehoover/compholio  
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Download the latest VMware Workstation Player for Linux version from the [official VMware website](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0).
3. Change directories using `cd` to the directory that the VMware .bundle file that you download is in:

   ```
   cd /path/to/directory/that/contains/VMware-bundle
   ```
4. Make the VMware Player bundle file executable.

   ```
   chmod +x VMware-Player-14.1.1-7528167.x86_64.bundle
   ```
5. Install VMware Player.

   ```
   sudo sh ./VMware-Player-14.1.1-7528167.x86_64.bundle
   ```
6. Install Open VMware Tools for virtual machines hosted on VMware. It is a suite of virtualization utilities and drivers to improve the functionality, user experience and administration of VMware virtual machines.

   ```
   sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop
   ```